# How to change enter key title for WebView inputs in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I have an Android app which uses WebView. All is fine except for the small problem: WebView changes `Enter` key title to "Go" (or similar) inappropriately. For example, there is a page with login form. When user fills in text inputs in the form, the enter key becomes blue "Go". Unfortunately, on some locales this is translated into "Find"/"Search". Apparently it's not applicable there.

How can I enforce WebView not to mangle `Enter` key name in softkeyboard, or change it back to default <kbd>↵</kbd>?

**UPD/HINT**: The file `WebTextView.java` contains [`setType`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/WebTextView.java#1012) method which makes it clear how WebView processes inputs in regard to IME. Unfortunately, in many cases the choice made in the code becomes irrelevant, and there is no a way for customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

↵ means "to the next line", it will show if you use TEXTAREA or ELEMENT with contenteditable set to "true".
You can use single line TEXTAREA (rows=1) to achieve this.
By the way, you cannot achieve this goal by changing IMEOptions because WebView configs these input elements each by each based on their own type.

Comment: &crarr; is just a default notation of Enter key. As I mentioned, I prefer to change this to a more appropriate string. Basically, the relevant part of your answer is "No, it's not possible". Right?

Comment: I'm afraid so, WebView sends suggested imeoptions and inputtype (i.e. EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO for normal case, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE for TEXTAREA, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE for telephone input type) to IME. IME will based on these suggestion to show their UI (implemented differently by each IME vendor). It is almost impossible to change what WebView suggested unless you override and rewrite entire InputConnection used by WebView.

Comment: It seems this is indeed impossible without some hacks (which are so hard that they're worthless to try). Unfortunately this looks like a bug in Android design, because, for example, `input type="password"` makes Enter key to show 'Go' or even 'Search' (in some locales), and this is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by messing with the IME options.

For example:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_field).setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Would make it say 'Done'. You can change the action to make it do different things.

You can also use the "imeOptions" attribute in the XML layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionLabel

Comment: My question is about WebView with `input` control inside a web-page. There is no such a thing like EditText with `R.id.your_field`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, read that part wrong. I didn't even think about fields _inside_ the WebView. I do see some references to using `android:imeOptions` in the HTML... sounds crazy enough it could work.